# How to add more data to a GeoTIFF file using GDAL

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have succesfully merged a number of ECW-files into one GeoTIFF file, `all.tif`. But I want to continuously add more raster data (coming from ECW files) to this TIFF.

I know it is possible to merge them together to a new file using *gdal_merge* or creating a GDAL virtual file and then using that as source for gdalwarp. But there are various reasons why I would like to simply modify/extend the existing geotiff file. One reason is that my current *all.tif* file will approach 1TB and I don't have a spare 1TB to make a copy of it.

How is this possible?

**Details (answering questions in comments):**

The *all.tif* file has been created using:

```
gdalwarp parts/*.ecw all.tif
```

If it matters I can use non default settings for the creation.

When more ecw files need to be added, some of these will be within the extent of *all.tif* and some will be outside the extent (unless I decide to start by creating the tiff with a very large margin of empty/transparent raster data so all future ecw files will fit inside).

All ECW files and all.tif have the same bands.

Comment: How is this TIFF file structured (dimensions, tiling, compression etc)? What does "add data" mean, is it spatially extending the coverage or is it bands, is it replacing data?

Comment: You can update existing pixels in a TIFF file but you cannot make is bigger (in pixels, width x height) without rewriting the whole TIFF. Even updating pixels may lead to same result if TIFF is compressed. I suggest to think again your workflow and base your service on a virtual VRT file, or maybe on  STAC https://stacspec.org/en. Updating 1 TB image file frequently feels really sub-optimal.

Comment: Depending on the processing required, you might be able to construct a VRT (Virtual Raster) file, which lets you do things like create virtual multi-layer spatial data sets that refer to the constituents. No extra storage needed.

Comment: @bugmenot123 I updated my question to answer your questions.